# CURL should be enable for facebook application?

Tags: facebook, curl

I am new to facebook application development.

I try to create facebook as per following url.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/design-and-code-an-integrated-facebook-app/

But I am getting following error.

I have hosted application on shared web hosting and do we need to have CURL enable to

facebook application.

I have CURL disabled on shared web hosting.

**Error
Sorry, the application you were using is experiencing a problem. Please try again later.**

I try to check from my local XAMPP and got CURL error and after I enable CURL error solve.

- Thanks

Comment: Yes, curl MUST be enabled for the Facebook API to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on how to get CURL enabled on PHP servers:

http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-find-out-if-php-is-compiled-with-curl-extension-installed-enabled-t1576.html